# Help!!! Old theme doesn't load scripts and conflitcs with plugins

Tags: themes, javascript

I need you help.
I am using an old theme for some time. Now I installed two plugins WP Job Manager and AD Inserter but they are not working properly.

Can someone give me a clue of what I can do to solve the problem.
For instance, the job listings are showing and secondly the ads are not showing as well.

Link to my site: http://zonga.co.mz/yeebo/

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need to talk to the theme authors for help sorry, unless you’re able to debug this yourself. You should try and prove it’s them at fault first if possible though else they’ll blame the plugin authors.

Comment: The bane of WordPress development is that every time you reach out to support the default answer is: "Oh, it's not my theme/plugin, it's an issue with another plugin."  LoL!